# Downloading images from publicly shared folder on Dropbox

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I received a link to shared folder from e-commerce company. The link is public and not shared with my dropbox account directly.

How do I get an url to the image that I can pass to either DownloadAsync method of the same sdk or simply  HttpClient and well ... download it?

Ideally it would be the same link I get when I click on the image when viewing that shared folder in a browser.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/{folder_hash}/{file_hash_maybe}/{filename}?dl=0
```

This is what I have tried:

```
using Dropbox.Api;
using Dropbox.Api.Files;
...
var accessToken = "abracadabra";
var sharedFolderUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/{folder_hash}?dl=0";

using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(accessToken))
{
    var sharedLink = new SharedLink(sharedFolderUrl);
    var sharedFiles = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(path: "", sharedLink: sharedLink);

    // sharedFiles - has over 13,000 entries, I use cursor to get them all.
    foreach (var file in sharedFiles.Entries)
    {
        if (file.IsFile)
        {
            // tried this, but:
            // 1. it's crazy to loop through all 
            // 2. link.Response.Url gives me the same url to a shared folder for all items 
            var link = await dbx.Sharing.GetSharedLinkFileAsync(url: sharedFolderUrl, path: "/" + file.Name);
        }
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `GetSharedLinkFileAsync` method is the right way to programmatically download a file from a shared link. It actually gives both the metadata (in the `link.Response` in your code like you mentioned), as well as the file data directly (not via a URL).

To access the file data, you can use any of the `GetContentAs...` methods documented under [`IDownloadResponse`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Stone_IDownloadResponse_1.htm) as returned by [`GetSharedLinkFileAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_GetSharedLinkFileAsync_1.htm). In your code, that would look something like: `link.GetContentAsStreamAsync()` (or whichever one you want).

Alternatively, if you want to download the entire folder from the shared link, you can use [the URL parameters documented in this help center article](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download). (That may fail for very large folders though.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The folder download fails (even in the browser) but looping through every single image with large set like in my case is ...well a bit crazy. Suggestion: since all images are public why not provide shareable url link within entries of `ListFolderResult`? Same link that is provided when viewing the folder in the browser.

The reason I'm asking is because in my case I'm running this code on system A but image download and processing happens on system B, so in this code I would like to get public url and queue it for processing with system B (over night).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't speak to why any particular feature was or wasn't implemented, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Greg !